# How do I get the value from an ngrx store into my template?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

A total Redux noob here, I am having a little difficulty getting my data out of the store for use within my view. Here are my Actions, Reducers etc.

**genre.model.ts**

```
export interface Genre {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    slug: string;
    error: string;
}

export const initialState: Genre = {
    id: '',
    title: '',
    description: '',
    slug: '',
    error: null
};
```

**genre.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import {environment} from "../../../environments/environment";
import {Genre} from "./genre.model";

@Injectable()
export class GenreService {

    apiUrl = environment.apiUrl + environment.apiVersion + '/';

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    /**
     * Gets Genres
     *
     * @returns {Observable<Genre[]>}
     */
    getGenres(): Observable<Genre[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + 'genres/')
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    /**
     * Gets an individual genre
     *
     * @param {String} slug
     * @returns {Observable<Genre[]>}
     */
    getGenre(slug: String): Observable<Genre[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + 'genres/' + slug)
            .map(res => res.json().genre);
    }
}
```

**genre.actions.ts**

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Genre } from '../_shared/genre.model';

@Injectable()
export class GenreActions {

    static LOAD_GENRES = '[Genre] Load Genres';
    loadGenres(): Action {
        return {
            type: GenreActions.LOAD_GENRES
        };
    }

    static LOAD_GENRES_SUCCESS = '[Genre] Load Genres Success';
    loadGenresSuccess(genres): Action {
        return {
            type: GenreActions.LOAD_GENRES_SUCCESS,
            payload: genres
        };
    }

    static GET_GENRE = '[Genre] Get Genre';
    getGenre(slug): Action {
        return {
            type: GenreActions.GET_GENRE,
            payload: slug
        };
    }

    static GET_GENRE_SUCCESS = '[Genre] Get Genre Success';
    getGenreSuccess(genre): Action {
        return {
            type: GenreActions.GET_GENRE_SUCCESS,
            payload: genre
        };
    }
}
```

**genre.reducers.ts**

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

import {Genre, initialState} from '../_shared/genre.model';

import { GenreActions } from './genre.actions';

export function genreReducer(state: Genre = initialState, action: Action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GenreActions.GET_GENRE_SUCCESS: {
            return action.payload;
        }
        case GenreActions.LOAD_GENRES_SUCCESS: {
            return action.payload;
        }
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
}
```

**genre.effects.ts**

```
export class GenreEffects {
    constructor (
        private update$: Actions,
        private genreActions: GenreActions,
        private svc: GenreService,
    ) {}

    @Effect() loadGenres$ = this.update$
        .ofType(GenreActions.LOAD_GENRES)
        .switchMap(() => this.svc.getGenres())
        .map(genres => this.genreActions.loadGenresSuccess(genres));

    @Effect() getGenre$ = this.update$
        .ofType(GenreActions.GET_GENRE)
        .map(action => action.payload)
        .switchMap(slug => this.svc.getGenre(slug))
        .map(genre => this.genreActions.getGenreSuccess(genre));
}
```

**genre.detail.component.ts**

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Genre } from '../_shared/genre.model';
import { GenreActions } from '../_store/genre.actions';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-genre-detail',
    templateUrl: './genre-detail.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./genre-detail.component.scss']
})
export class GenreDetailComponent implements OnInit {

    public idSub: Subscription;
    public genre: Observable<any>;

    constructor(
        private store: Store<Genre>,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private genreActions: GenreActions,
        private router: Router
    ) {
        this.genre = store.select('genres');
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.idSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.store.dispatch(this.genreActions.getGenre(params['slug']));
            console.log(this.genre);
            });
    }
}
```

I can see that my API request is being fired, and it is return data, I can see in the Redux devtools that state is being populated but I just can't seem to get the data out and in to my views using the normal `{{ genre.title }}` I just get `[Object object]` being thrown back at me?

I am sure that this might be something really easy but like I said I am a total noob and have spent around 5 hours on this trying out different things following different tutorials etc.

[image: Console]

Comment: What ia the version of ngrx are you using?

Comment: Also as you are using effects its is an async call you need to subscribe in the select. Like `select('genre'). subscribe (data => data)`

Comment: ngrx store version 2.2.2

Comment: did you try subscribing to the select? As i pointed out

Comment: Yes, changing `this.genre = store.select('genres')` to `this.genre = store.select('genres').subscribe(data => data)` results in further errors due to the Type: `public genre: Observable<any>;`

Comment: it will be like this `store.select('genres').subscribe(data => this.genre = data) `

Comment: I have changed `public genre: Observable<any>;` to just `public genre` as this was causing a type error, genre is `undefined` when console logging & nothing appears in the template for `{{ genre }}`

Comment: you are confused  with ngrx i guess can a you create a small plunker for the same, i have a web page featuring ngrx but i had just recently ugraded to v 4.0 so i cannot show a example of v 2.2.2

Comment: updating a answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am guessing your genre is a list of array

It should be some thing like this take it as wireframe.

```
genre : any ;

ngOnInit(){
 this.idSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
   this.store.dispatch(this.genreActions.getGenre(params['slug']));
   });
   this.store.select('genres').subscribe(data => this.genre = data)
}
```

If you want to look up to ngrx 4 look at this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx)

I just dug up my git you can check this snapshot of my repo of using ngrx v2 . I donot have a working example for the same but rest assured the code workes [LINK](https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts/tree/c5a2107e19a4155bade36e405fe62fba2c28f7d3/src/app/ngrx)

**UPDATE**

Make a different Object for Genre to use the Genre interface in state

```
export interface AppState {
    genre:Genre
}
```

Now Subscribe to this state object genre in the constructor or ngOnInit

```
private store: Store<AppState>, 
private route: ActivatedRoute, 
private genreActions: GenreActions, 
private router: Router 
) { 
this.store.select('genre').subscribe(data => this.genre = data); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the jist of what is going on in your example, mine looks almost identical. I am being believe that it is something with the way that ngrx/effects is returning the result. I replaces item with genre (from your example) and I am still getting the same issue, if I console log this.genre in the ngInit then I get the STORE object back in my console.

Comment: Can you print the store result how it comming for you

Comment: Updated the question with a screenshot :)

Comment: Can you try this this.store.select('id').subscribe(data =>  console.log(data));

Comment: Yep that gives me the ID of the genre: `2984df33-352d-4d7a-8ef2-d278940218a4`

Comment: aha this is what i though was the issue , you have to create a nested object for the state for now what is happening is that all are individual elements of state and you need to fetch them one by one or subscribe to the whole store i:e get the whole store select . store . hope it solves the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152079/discussion-between-seriousjelly-and-rahul-singh).

Comment: @SeriousJelly updated the discussion in chat as an answer phew was hard :p

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are getting just the Observable but expecting the list of genre. And, that is the problem. You need to subscribe it to get the value.

Make a different Object for Genre to use the Genre interface in state (as Rahul Singh told already)

```
export interface AppState {
    genre:Genre
}

constructor(private store: Store<AppState>,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private genreActions: GenreActions, 
    private router: Router) {}
```

and in ngOnInit subscribe it to obeserve the change.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.select(s => s.genre).subscribe(data => this.genre = data);
}
```

**Note**: `ngOnInit()` is used to make sure that the component's properties (for example:  `@Input() someId: number`) you used are already initialized . So, If you use any component properties you should do it in `ngOnInit()`. otherwise `constructor()` is fine.
but we should use `constructor()` to setup Dependency Injection and not much else. `ngOnInit()` is better place to "start" - it's where/when components' bindings are resolved.